# Retrieve email HTML from a running triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

does anyone know of a way to retrieve the Email body (HTML and ampscript) from an already started triggered send? We want to get the code for the email that's been cached for the triggered send. Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way for you to pull this information. I looked at the different SOAP objects and they will only return the current email HTML and not the HTML being used in the triggeredsend. However MC Support can pull this info and provide it.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with the lack of access via the API. I'll retry with support.